# Show a preloader image while append a huge image in the html body

Tags: jquery, load, append, preloader

I need to show a preloader image before append a huge image in the html body. In my script, a tooltip with a image is showed on a mouseover event only after it is complete loaded. The image takes too long to be completed. Meanwhile I want to show something on the page.

```
this.screenshotPreview = function(){    
xOffset = 10;
yOffset = 30;
$('a.screenshot').hover(function(e){
    this.t = this.title;
    this.title = '';    
    var c = (this.t != '') ? '<br/>' + this.t : '';
    $('body').append('<p id="screenshot"><img src="images/image.png" alt="Url preview" />'+ c +'</p>');
    $('#screenshot')
    .css('top',(e.pageY - xOffset) + 'px')
    .css('left',(e.pageX + yOffset) + 'px')
    .fadeIn('fast');                        
},
function(){
   this.title = this.t; 
   $('#screenshot').remove();
}); 
$('a.screenshot').mousemove(function(e){
    $('#screenshot')
    .css('top',(e.pageY - xOffset) + 'px')
    .css('left',(e.pageX + yOffset) + 'px');
});         
};

// starting the script on page load
$(document).ready(function(){
screenshotPreview();
});
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please set preloader background image on this div #screenshot,

when this div appending , BG will show before showing IMG huge image

Comment: so you have to click Reputation score .. :)